# Can't get list of uploaded images

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the example that has on the @Creativedream plugin page **jQuery.filer 1.0.3** (https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer), but I am unable to retrieve the list (names) of the Images I have uploaded.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="teste">
    <!-- filer 2 -->
    <a class="file_input" data-jfiler-name="files" data-jfiler-extensions="jpg, jpeg, png, gif"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Adicionar Fotos</a>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">
</form>
```

**My Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.file_input').filer({
        imit: null,
        maxSize: null,
        extensions: null,
        changeInput: true,
        showThumbs: true,
        appendTo: null,
        theme: "default",
        templates: {
            box: '<ul class="jFiler-item-list"></ul>',
            item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                        <li>{{fi-progressBar}}</li>\
                                        <li><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}} {{fi-size2}}</span></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>',
            itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}} {{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                    </ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>',
            progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>',
            itemAppendToEnd: false,
            removeConfirmation: true,
            _selectors: {
                list: '.jFiler-item-list',
                item: '.jFiler-item',
                progressBar: '.bar',
                remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action',
            }
        },
        /*uploadFile: {
            url: "assets/php/upload.php",
            data: {},
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data, el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Concluido</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            error: function(el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Erro</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            statusCode: {},
            onProgress: function(){},
            onComplete: function(){
                console.log("Completed");
            }
        },*/
        dragDrop: {
            dragEnter: null,
            dragLeave: null,
            drop: null,
        },
        addMore: true,
        clipBoardPaste: true,
        files: null,
        excludeName: null,
        beforeShow: function(){return true},
        onSelect: function(){},
        afterShow: function(){},
        onRemove: function(){},
        onEmpty: function(){},
        captions: {
            button: "Escolher Arquivos",
            feedback: "Escolher arquivos para Upload",
            feedback2: "arquivos escolhidos",
            drop: "Solte os arquivos aqui para o Upload",
            removeConfirmation: "Tem certeza que deseja remover este arquivo?",
            errors: {
                filesLimit: "Somente {{fi-limit}} arquivos são permitidos para o upload.",
                filesType: "Somente imagens são permitidos para o upload.",
                filesSize: "{{fi-name}} é muito pesado! Escolha um arquivo com no máximo {{fi-maxSize}} MB.",
                filesSizeAll: "Os arquivos que você escolheu são muito grandes! Por favor, faça upload de arquivos de até {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
            }
        }
    });

    $("#teste").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "assets/php/upload.php",
            data: {},
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            //dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
            success: function(data, el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Concluido</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });

                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Erro</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            }

        })

    });

});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Creativedream Can you help me with this?